# How can i handle Server authentication pop-up in Internet Explorer in Selenium Webdriver using JAVA?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I want to run Automated test cases on a URl having server authentication. In Firefox & Chrome i am handling it by passing the URl like below:

`http://username:password@url.com`

It is not working in IE (Windows 8.1). I have googled it, But no luck.

After some changes in registry, able to get server authentication pop-up in IE. But now please some one please tell me how to handle the Server authentication pop-up using Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: Whats kind of pop-up it is? A modal dialog box or a simple alert?

Comment: Please try the suggestion by hirtenfelder , if not working give a try by using Robot class.

Comment: i personally do not think machine level registry hacks are a solid way to accomplish test passes. in the real world such an issue would come back to haunt you. I think you would be better to use the `_driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle)`  (or `_driver.SwitchTo().Frame(targetFrame)` if more applicable) route to achieve your aim with more coverage across a wide range of browsers.

Comment: @jimtollan Again the modal dialog window will not support driver.switchTo method. I think we should either use Robot class or Sikuli or any other tool to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not support user names and passwords in Web site addresses (HTTP or HTTPS URLs). See [KB834489](https://support.microsoft.com/de-ch/kb/834489/en-us).

But you can enable it. Create a DWORD iexplore.exe/0 in Windows Registry for

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node/Microsoft/Internet Explor-er/MAIN/FeatureControl/FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE

and

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Internet 
Explorer/MAIN/FeatureControl/FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this already. After these changes also on accessing the URL it is asking for username & pwd in authentication pop-up

Comment: For me the solution described in [KB834489](https://support.microsoft.com/de-ch/kb/834489/en-us) solved my Basic Authentication issue for Internet Explorer. The second configuration I did was, to enable Protected Mode to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. Alternativly I set the flag `ignoreProtectedModeSettings` to `true`. But this is an other topic. According to your description, can we assume that the test runs if you disable the basic authentication in your application?